# Trigger Jenkins build only if there was a git commit in that repo which is not configured in pipeline definiton

Tags: git, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-build-flow

I have two Git repository A and B. 
I'm using Jenkins Pipeline for the build, with Pipeline Definition "Pipeline script from SCM" and am calling "Jenkinsfile" to trigger the build.

I have one dependency due to which I need to give Repository A in my pipeline definition on Jenkins. The Jenkinsfile of Repo "A" clone the Repo "B".

My requirement is to trigger the build only if any change is made into Repo "B". Please note in Jenkins as I mentioned earlier I have configured Repo "A". While I know we can have a Git Webhook configured for Repo "A", I'm not sure how we can configure Git Webhook in this case for Repo "B".

**So, Is it possible to achieve what I want via Poll SCM? OR Is there any other way via which it can be achieved?**

Thanks

Comment: If Repo B is the only one that needs to trigger the build, why don't you configure repo B as a source repo?

Comment: A - It has build scripts which I can't share in Repo B. This script only trigger the build by cloning Repo B followed by other CI/CD pipeline
B - This has my application code, and here only commits are made often.

That's the reason I can't configure Repo B. Because If I do so, I would have to share my scripts in Repo B.

Please feel free to share any other way also via which this can be achieved. Thanks